# Use jQuery to move DOM element's position across the screen from a keypress?

Tags: jquery, keystroke

I would like to move a DOM element once the right arrow key is pressed.

The distance the element moves should be directly proportional to the length of the right arrow keypress.

I was thinking that perhaps I could use this jQuery plugin to find out when the right arrow key is being pressed down, and then add a certain value to the element's `left` css value to make it seem like it's being moved.

However, I don't know exactly how to make this work.  Is it better not to use the plugin and just use the jQuery's methods involved with keystrokes?  I just need some help finding out the easiest and most effective way to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be something like this using only jquery where the div you want to move has ID="d"

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    var offset = 5;
    if(e.keyCode == '39') {
        var pos = $("#d").position();
        $("#d").css('left', pos.left + offset);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == '37') {
        var pos = $("#d").position();
        $("#d").css('left',pos.left - offset);
    }
});
```

Note that the div has to have

```
 position:absolute;
```

Comment: Nice!  That's pretty succinct.  I'm going to try and extend this approach to make my sprite (I'm working on a game of sorts) jump.  Thanks!